# How can I troubleshoot the delete row function

Tags: r, row

I am attempting to delete a row like this:

`data <- data[-1645,]`

However, after running the code, the row is still there. I can tell because there is an outlier in that row that is showing up on all my graphs, and when I view the data I can sort a column to easily find the offending outlier. I have had no trouble deleting rows in the past- has anyone run into anything similar? I do understand the limitations of outlier removal and I don't typically remove them however for a number of reasons I would like to see what the data look like without this one (in this case, all other values in the response variable are between -1 and 0, and in this row the value is 10^4).

Comment: Can you show the `dput` or `str(data)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with the data, I think the best explanation is that the indexing is off. This is in line with what dcarlson was saying- that it could be removing the 1,645th row, it just isn't labelled as such. I think the best solution is to use subset:

`data <- subset(data, Yield.Decline < 100)`

This is a more robust solution than trying to remove any given row based on its value (the line can be accidentally run multiple times without erroneously removing additional lines).

Answer (score 1):

You really need to provide more information, but there are several ways you can troubleshoot the problem. The first one is to print out the line you are removing:

data[1645, ]

Is that the outlier? You did not tell us how you identified the outlier. If lines have been removed from the data frame, the row names are not changed but the index values are changed, e.g.

```
set.seed(42)
x <- sample.int(25)
y <- sample.int(25)
data <- data.frame(x, y)
head(data)
#    x  y
# 1 17  2
# 2  5  8
# 3  1  3
# 4 10  1
# 5  4 10
# 6 18 11
data <- data[-c(5, 10, 15, 20, 25), ]
head(data)
#    x  y
# 1 17  2
# 2  5  8
# 3  1  3
# 4 10  1
# 6 18 11
# 7 25 15
data[6, ]
#    x  y
# 7 25 15
data["6", ]
#    x  y
# 6 18 11
```

Notice that the 6th row of the data has a row name of "7" but the row with name "6" is the 5th row in the data frame because we deleted the 5th row. The `which` function will give you the index value, but if you identified the outlier by looking at the printout, you got the row name and that may be different from the index. If we want to remove values in x greater than 24, here is one way to do that:

```
data[data$x<25, ]
```

Comment: I have been using indexing to identify this row after each time I've attempted to remove it. It's not the case that I'm seeing "1645" and thinking the outlier is still there, I'm looking for the value associated with that line. Your alternate code worked, but it added 300 NA lines to my data frame. At this point I'll take it. Thanks!!!